# Toggling list image and expand all jquery accordion w/ unordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I have a functioning jquery accordion using pure unordered lists. I'm trying to incorporate 2 pieces of functionality.

[Here is my functioning accordion code and a demo of it working.](http://jsbin.com/itibi4/)
http://jsbin.com/itibi4/

1. Toggling Arrows.

i'm tring to get the parent bullets to be a toggling arrow and point down when clicked while the child bullets stay as bullets instead of an arrow. Would I be able to get some help with this?

```
.inactive { 
background-image:url("http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/4103/arrowp.gif");
background-position:4px -31px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
padding-left:20px;
padding-top:10px;
}

.active {
background-image: url("http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/4103/arrowp.gif");
background-position: 4px 12px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

1. Expand All / Collapse All

also, i'm trying to incorporate an expand all / collapse all functionality. [this is code to the same demo](http://jsbin.com/itibi4/) the code is from a previous project, which i've added below the unordered list menu, but i'm having difficulty incorporating it into this project. Would I be able to get some help with this?

```
$('.swap').click(function()

          {
            if($(this).text() == 'Click to Collapse All FAQs')
            {
              $('ul.menu').slideUp('normal');
              $('ul.menu li a').removeClass('active');
              $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Click to Expand All FAQs' ? 'Click to Collapse All FAQs' : 'Click to Expand All FAQs');
            }
            else
            {
              $('ul.menu').slideDown('normal');
              $('ul.menu li a').addClass('active');
              $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Click to Expand All FAQs' ? 'Click to Collapse All FAQs' : 'Click to Expand All FAQs');
            }
          }
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Evan

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a closing parentheses at the end of your click handler:

```
 $('.swap').click(function()

      {
         if($(this).text() == 'Click to Collapse All FAQs')
         {
           $('ul.menu').slideUp('normal');
           $('ul.menu li a').removeClass('active');
           $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Click to Expand All FAQs' ? 'Click to Collapse All FAQs' : 'Click to Expand All FAQs');
         }
         else
         {
           $('ul.menu').slideDown('normal');
           $('ul.menu li a').addClass('active');
           $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Click to Expand All FAQs' ? 'Click to Collapse All FAQs' : 'Click to Expand All FAQs');
         }
      }

  );  // this was missing!
```

I added your function in my Chrome JavaScript console, and it worked.

As for your arrows, the following rule currently makes them point to the right:

ul.menu li

If you create a copy of that rule called ul.menu li.down and make the following changes:

```
      background-position: 4px 0px;
      padding-top: 0px;
```

Then make sure class="down" is bound to the arrows you want to be pointing down.  You may have to tweak these values, but this will definitely get you started.

Comment: @jmort253 thanks for the missing bracket tip. i made the change here http://jsbin.com/itibi4/2/ i guess now i need support on is how to make the sub unordered list expand and collapse instead of the main unordered list. i think i can handle the arrows you pointed out. thank you for that tip.

Comment: @Evan - Your expand/collapse function is probably bound to the toplevel menus.  You'll need to expand it to be bound to all the menus.  Try to find a way to use a CSS selector that is bound to all menus and you'll be good to go!

Comment: @jmort253 okay. i got it. now, i have another problem. when i click "expand", everything expands perfectly, but as soon as i click on any of the programs (business admin) the links all collapse. they all shouldn't collapse like that. here's a demo of my latest http://jsbin.com/itibi4/3/

Comment: @Evan - What I would suggest is that you define a completely different set of behavior for all of your click handlers when expanded.  Right now, it's configured to behave a certain way.  You'll need to go through these bugs one by one until the behavior is modified as per your expectations.  You're making progress!  Good luck!

Comment: @jmort253 okay. although it's not idea, i made it so a user can't close them individually when all links are expanded, which fixes the issue mentioned above. only when all links are collapsed, is the user able to expand them by clicking each program one by one. demo here: http://jsbin.com/itibi4/4/ i now must get those silly arrows working properly.... meh. note: there's a cookie session tied to this. if a user should be taken to a different page and clicks the back button, the link the user clicks will stay open.

Comment: I was looking for something along these very lines